# css not supported in iphone 7

Tags: ios, css, iphone

I given CSS properties for responsive screen and it is supported in google developer tool by customising screen size as 1334 and 750 for iphone 7 also 375 included since suggested to add,but the same is not working in iphone 7 phone .Need a solution

```
@media screen and (min-width:351px) and (max-width:384px) {

        .titSech{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0
        color:#1D0B57;
        color:#1D0B57!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
}

 @media screen and (min-width:690px) and (max-width:769px)  { 
    .titSech{
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            transform: rotate(270deg);
            transform-origin: left top 0
                color:#1D0B57;
                color:#1D0B57!important;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    }
```

[image: snapshot in iphone7]

[image: snapshot in google developer]

Snapshot in iphone 7 and 
snapshot in google developer

[image: snapshot in google developer for 375px]

Comment: 750 is the retina size for iphone 7.So the actual size is 375. Please update media query accordingly and let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried 375 too its responsive.

Comment: Did 375 worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
  @media (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 769px)  { 

    .titSech{
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
          -ms-transform-origin: left top 0 
           color:#1D0B57;
           transform-origin: left top 0 
           color:#1D0B57;
           -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0
            color:#1D0B57;
            -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
            transform: rotate(270deg);
            color:#1D0B57!important;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Please share the url I will manually check and come back to you?

Comment: 35.154.125.35 please check this